# RabbitMQ take one message from queue on launch

Tags: rabbitmq

I publish many messages to my queue in RabbitMQ when worker is off.
Then i start my worker and he takes all messages from queue and he is working fine but when i stop my worker proces before he ends, all messages are deleted from queue.
If i start second the same worker he has no messages to take.

```
$channel->queue_declare($action, false, false, false, false);

$channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
$channel->basic_consume($action, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);
```

How can i do to my worker takes only one message on start from queue and when worker stops and starts he continue takes messages from queue where he stops ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no messages left to take the messages have already been acknowledged.

"Auto acknowledgements" should be *disabled* so that an acknowledgement must be explicitly sent back manually (ie. after all work is done) to complete consuming the message.

```
$no_ack = false; # If no_ack is true the server does NOT expect a
                 # basic.ack response and will dequeue the message immediately!
$channel->basic_consume($action, '', false, $no_ack, false, false, $callback);
```

The [PHP tutorial on the RabbitMQ site](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html) shows how to send an ack from within the callback.

As long as the worker is killed *before* the ack has been sent the message will be made available again when the connection is closed - and can be picked up by other consumers. See [Message Acknowledgements](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

Specifically, wrt the [no-ack](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#domain.no-ack]) bit:

> *If this field is set (true) the server does not expect acknowledgements for messages. That is, when a message is delivered to the client the server assumes the delivery will succeed and immediately dequeues it.* This functionality may increase performance but at the cost of reliability. Messages can get lost if a client dies before they are delivered to the application.

Comment: It looks good, but i don't know how now i can sent back information that message is complete consumed.

Comment: @BartekPieczonka Use the `bacic_ack` method (corresponding to the `basic.ack` command). The PHP library documentation is .. crap, but it's the same principle among the different clients. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html and note `$msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);`